# How to set variable value based on current ticker symbol value in pine script?

Tags: pine-script, trading

I want to create price target lines, and I have this code so far but it doesn't work.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script")
yy = 0.0
if syminfo.tickerid == "BATS:ADMP"
    yy := 1
line.new(bar_index - 1, yy, bar_index, yy, width = 1)
label.new(bar_index, high, text=syminfo.tickerid)
plot(close)
```

This part here `syminfo.tickerid == "BATS:ADMP"` never equals true. How can I compare it?

Thanks

Comment: Can you attach a screenshot of your chart? I just copied your code and there are no issues. It does draw a line at 1. Note that you are assigning 1 to `yy` if it's `BATS:ADMP`, so the line will be at 1.

Answer (score 0):

Your `syminfo.tickerid` probably `NASDAQ:ADMP`, not `BATS:ADMP`.

For this cases:

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script")

yy = 0.0
i = input.symbol("ADMP")

if syminfo.tickerid == i
    yy := 1

if barstate.islastconfirmedhistory
    label.new(bar_index, high, text=syminfo.tickerid)
    
plot(yy)
```